# Angular schematic is not creating files from templates

Tags: angular, typescript, templates, angular-schematics

I've created an angular schematic for the purposes of creating boilerplate code with an ng generate command, however despite all the articles I've read through and messing about, I cannot get the files to create.

**I've the following code in my schematic factory:**

```
export function createComponent(_options: any): Rule {
    return (tree: Tree, _context: SchematicContext) => {
        setupOptions(tree, _options);

        const movePath = normalize(_options.path + '/' + strings.dasherize(_options.name));

        const templateSource = apply(url('./files'), [
            template({
                ...strings,
                ..._options,
            }),
            move(movePath)
        ]);

        return mergeWith(templateSource);
    };
}
```

In the same directory as this is a files directory containing my "__name@dasherize__.component.ts" template which I'm expecting to get pulled in as part of the url('./files') function but I'm not sure this is happening.

**My template file is as follows:**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
    selector: 'wx-<%= dasherize(componentName) %>'
})
export class <%= classify(componentName) %>Component {

}
```

I'd expect a 'CREATE'  to appear when I run the schematic but all I get is 'Nothing to be done.'

Oddly enough using tree.create() is successfully running to create files so I wonder if the url() or apply() functions are not running as expected.

Comment: can provide github repo?

Comment: @HsuanLee No I can't, is there anything in particular you're looking for? I have other schematics working within this library but they do not create files.

Answer (score 4):

Make sure that "./files" is a correct path relative to your schematic file inside the **dist** folder.

Maybe you need to change it to something like: "../../src/my-schematic/files".

Answer (score 4):

Had the same problem but looking both at the source and docs [Schematics for Libraries](https://angular.io/guide/schematics-for-libraries) template file should end with `.ts.template` extension.

So in your case the file should be named `__name@dasherize__.component.ts.template`.

The output file will **not** contain `.template` extension.

Link to @angular/devkit source: [applyTemplates()](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/blob/23589ed00e68e4ff9e0fda0d61a4861eac259c55/packages/angular_devkit/schematics/src/rules/template.ts#L184)

Answer (score 2):

A colleague had a similar issue and regardless of how I changed his code, it still seemed to do the same annoying thing.

It came down to the command that was used to run the schematics in the first place.

Before:

`node_modules/.bin/schematics ./schematics:my-schematic-name --parameter`

**What it should be:**

`ng generate schematics:my-schematic-name --parameter`

Your schematic needs to run in the context of the Angular CLI, by simply executing it in Node, it doesn't seem to output any files but still somehow succeeds in its execution.

Answer (score 0):

Look at your .npmignore and .gitignore.
Maybe you are ignoring all .ts wich makes that all your files with .ts under /files folder will be ignored.

Your .npmignore may look like this:

```
# .npmignore
# Ignores TypeScript files, but keeps definitions and .ts under /files folder.
*.ts
!*.d.ts
!/src/**/files/*.ts
```

Remember to do a npm run build to build your ts definitions before update your npm package.